# How to restrict access to object for one specific class in Java? If possible, by implementing a design pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am writing a code where I have some SharedData object(single object) between Admin object(single object) and User objects. Only one person(Admin or User) should be able to access SharedData at a time, I am using synchronised locks currently. For accessing SharedData, currently I am keeping the SharedData object in the Admin and User class.
The problem is I want to restrict Users from changing some members of SharedData. But, the Admin object should still be able to change SharedData.

**Note: The admin and user classes are very different, I can't extend user to create Admin. Admin is not just like user here.**
Some code for better understanding
SharedData

```
public class SharedData {
    public ArrayList<Integer> numbersShown = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public boolean completeFlag = false;    
}
```

```
public class Admin implements Runnable {
    
    private SharedData SharedData;
    //OTHER MEMBERS
    run()
    {
    //Change numberShown
    }

}
public class User implements Runnable {
    
    private SharedData SharedData;
    //OTHER MEMBERS
    run()
    {
    //not able to change numberShown
    }
}
```

Comment: Use setters so in the SharedData class you can check if it is the admin class.

Comment: Why are you keeping sharedData as an instance variable? How is that useful for you?

Comment: If `User` and `Admin` are not related to each other and don't share common implementations, I don't see why you don't just never implement code where `User` changes the object you are talking about. It seems to me as if the methods you are talking about just do too much and your program lacks proper seperation of responsibilities. If you put much logic into one method, you'll have a hard time making it flexible like here. Just split it up into smaller methods and create specialized methods for both types of accessors.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent `User` from changing `SharedData` members if they are public. Perhapes you could do the following:

1. Change the members access to `private` or `protected`.
2. Implement a read-only proxy to the `SharedData` which is given to the `Users`.

```java
    public ReadOnlySharedData extends SharedData {
        public List<Integer> setNumbersShown(List<Integer> numbersShown) {
            throw new RuntimeException("You cannot changed read-only data");
        }
        
        public boolean setCompleteFlag(boolean flag) {
            throw new RuntimeException("You cannot changed read-only data");
        }
    }
```

You provide the `Admin` with a real instance of `SharedData` and `Users` with this proxy instance. They are both instances of `SharedData`.

If you want to do some sophiticated verification who is calling this method, the proxy pattern may also be a good candidate (without changing the proxied object).

Comment: I believe it's called protection proxy

Answer (score 0):

If you invert the class hierarchy proposed by @Lini, you can give the admins an object that is extended with additional methods for modification:

```java
public class SharedData {
    public List<Integer> getNumbersShown();
}

public class MutableSharedData extends SharedData {
    public void setNumbersShown(List<Integer> newNumbersToShow);
}
```

```java
public class Admin {
   private MutableSharedData sharedData;
}

public class User {
    private SharedData sharedData;
}
```

I do not know if there is a name for this design pattern.

This design has some nice advantages:

- The types prevent misuse. The `User` class doesn't have access to any modification methods.  Furthermore, it doesn't even have access to "dummy" modification methods that throw exceptions.
- Admins and users can share the same reference to a `MutableSharedData` object. This is a minuscule optimization, but worth noting.

You might be concerned that the `User` implementation can modify the list returned by `getNumbersShown()`. To prevent misuse, common practice is to have `getNumbersShown()` return a copy of the list or wrap it with [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-).